# Call a Stored Procedure in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, xml, mybatis, ibatis

Im using SqlServer and MyBatis.

Been looking for several examples online but nothing seems to fit my need.
The stored_procedure Im calling accepts 5 parameters and returns 1 value- for example

give_discount (FirstName, LastName,Gender, DateOfBirth, Age )

all of which are strings. The stored_procedure then returns a STRING which is supposed to tell you how much discount you're entitled to.

Those five attributes (FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Age, Gender) are stored in a POJO named Person.java

So let's say I created an instance of Person.java

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.setFirstName("Joe");
person1.setLastName("Higashi");
person1.setGender("M");
person1.setDateOfBirth("1990-01-01");
person1.setAge("29");
```

this is my mapperXML

```
 <resultMap id = "discountValueParams"  type="com.test.Person">
      <result property = "FirstName"    column = "FirstName"/>
      <result property = "LastName"     column = "LastName"/>
      <result property = "Gender"       column = "Gender"/>
      <result property = "DateOfBirth"  column = "DateOfBirth"/>
      <result property = "Age"          column = "Age"/>
 </resultMap>
```

So the question is:

How do I pass **person1** to my stored_procedure so it will use its currently assigned values and return a value?

Is this correct in XML mapper?

```
<select id = "getDiscountValue" resultType = "String" parameterType = "com.test.Person" statementType = "CALLABLE">
  {call dbo.get_discount_value(
       #{FirstName,  jdbcType = NVARCHAR},
       #{LastName,  jdbcType = NVARCHAR},
       #{Gender,  jdbcType = NVARCHAR},
       #{DateOfBirth,  jdbcType = NVARCHAR},
       #{"Age",  jdbcType = NVARCHAR}
   )}
```

And the java method is:

```
public String getDiscountMethod( Person person) {

            String discountValue= "";

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("FirstName", person.getFirstName  );
            map.put("LastName", person.getLastName());
            map.put("Gender", person.getGender());
            map.put("DateOfBirth", person.getBday());
            map.put("Age", person.getAge());

            SqlSession session = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
            try {
                XmlMapper xmlmapper = session.getMapper(XmlMapper.class);
                discountValue= applicationMapper.getDiscountValue(map) ;
                session.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return discountValue;
```

}

```
mapperInterface.java
public interface UpstreamXmlMapper {
     public String callStoredProcedure (StoredProcRef storedProcRef);
}
```

Given these lines, how do I make the proper call? I know Im lacking and obviously may have erroneously implemented something. 
Need proper guidance.

Updated:

Stored Procedure variables in SqlServer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_discount_for_customer]
    @formCode nvarchar(50),
    @locationCode nvarchar(10),
    @gender nvarchar(1),
    @dateOfBirth date,
    @labResultFormId bigint
AS
..SP body ..
```

**

**

Comment: It's pretty much the same as the [example](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/master/so-58230726) that I shared previously. According to your explanation, there should be 6 parameters (5 IN params and 1 OUT) passed to `dbo.get_discount_value` (it's not a FUNCTION, is it?). The point is that the OUT param is set to the POJO (or map) and is not a return value of the mapper method. If you could share a demo app like that on GitHub, I (or someone) may be able to provide a direct solution.

Comment: @ave thanks for pointing the number of parameters, obv i have no idea that the returned value counts as well. it's stored_procedures.
yeh about the example you gave, im looking back and forth.lemme check again. and thank you again for the reply

Comment: @ave follow up question, the stored_procedure returns  7 columns, but I only want to fetch the 'discount_value' column, is that possible?

Comment: All declared parameters must be present in the statement call. Otherwise, you'll get an error like "Procedure or function 'get_discount_value' expects parameter 'xxx', which was not supplied".

Comment: @ave yes, im going to pass the whole 5 parameters in the statement call. Upon successful call, the stored_procedure returns 7 columns most of which I dont need . I only need the "discount_value" column so I was asking if I could make like a SELECT discount_value from the results of the successful stored_procedure call.

Comment: I think you should add the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. I don't understand how the procedure can "return 7 columns" while taking only 5 params...

Comment: @ave Are you familiar with this error:  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid java.sql.Types constant value -9 passed to set or update method.

Im gradually progressing, thanks to you. BTW you can post your comment as answer,  I can upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got it.
Your procedure returns 7 columns from a query, right?

I'll explain using the following simple table and a procedure.

```sql
create table users (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  note varchar(20)
);
```

```sql
create procedure MY_PROC 
  @ARG1 varchar(10)
as
begin
  select * from users where name = @ARG1;
end
```

The procedure returns 3 columns (`id`, `name` and `note`).
I'll show you a way to return only `note` column.

The mapper method would look as follows (you can use POJO instead of Map).

```java
List<Map<String, ?>> myProc(String arg1);
```

If it always returns one row, it can be...

```java
Map<String, ?> myProc(String arg1);
```

And here are the result map and the statement:

```xml
<resultMap type="map" id="userRM" autoMapping="false">
  <id column="id" />
  <result column="note" property="note" />
</resultMap>

<select id="myProc" statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="userRM">
  {call MY_PROC(#{arg1, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR})}
</select>
```

The returned map(s) will have one entry with a key `"note"`.

- `<id />` may not be necessary, but it's a good practice to supply it.
- `autoMapping="false"` is to avoid unnecessary columns to be auto-mapped.

An executable demo project:
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-58802623

Comment: you've been very helpful, can you check 1 last time what im missing, posted all of my relevant code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835141/mybatis-java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-java-sql-types-constant-value-9-passed?noredirect=1#comment103947094_58835141